# How to set navigationIcon color white in toolbar?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, menu, toolbar

[image]

I use toolbar in my application, when I inflate menu in toolbar, navigationIcon color is too dark. I want to set navigationIcon color = white, but I don't know how to do it. Please tell me what can I do?

xml:

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/dark"
    android:elevation="0dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgbtn_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_back_dark"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="開單作業"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="地"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="回"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

java:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
```

menu_main:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<group>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:title="補印"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_exit"
        android:title="補拍"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</group>
```

Comment: Did you try ```toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);``` i use it with button an it word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the Overflow Menu Icon color via xml define a custom style in styles.xml file and change the `android:tint` property like below:

```
<style name="MyToolBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:tint">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

and you can use this style in Toolbar using the `android:theme` attribute like below:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:theme="@style/MyToolBarTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

or in case you want to change it programmatically you can do it like below:

```
if(toolbar.getOverflowIcon()!=null)
  toolbar.getOverflowIcon().setTint(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve this could be adding a custom style in your styles.xml with the desidered color

```
<style name="ToolbarColoredIcons" parent="">
     <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

And then apply this style to your toolbar

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/dark"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredIcons">
```